# why float type pointer addressing int showing unknown numbers?

Tags: c, pointers

why this code is showing value of a = 1120403456 (may be garbage) in Dev-C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    float * pf;
    pf=(float *)&a;
    *pf=100.0;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking an integer to be a float with this line `pf=(float *)&a;`

Comment: Yes, why did you program this in the first place? Just because C offers the power of pointers doesn't mean you have to use them purely for the sake of it and write messes like this.

Comment: Why do you think it's showing that value?  Please explain fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating point number 100.0 is represented as 0x42C80000 in memory, which in decimal is 1120403456.  You're printing out the 32-bit integer representation of 100.0.

Comment: I was talking about your own answer. You couldn't downvote that even if you wanted to. :P

Comment: Gotcha, thought you were talking about the original question.

Comment: thanks, and when I storing float variable address in integer type pointer,and changing value by that pointer showing value of x=0.00.. float x=10;int *p=(int *)&x; *p=100; printf("%f",x);

Comment: @vinaynegi So, what good does that do? It's not like this is even one of C's useful low-level 'features', since floating point representation isn't guaranteed between platforms. There is no usefulness to these hacks, unless you happen to be an embedded programmer with a very tight deadline and a customised compiler. Of all the things you could be learning at this stage, the no-man's land of type-punning through pointers is possibly the most counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

```
*pf=100.0;
```

As you dereference this , your program invokes *undefined behaviour* as it violates [strict aliasing rule](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html) .And the value you get is due to *UB* .

Comment: Why the downvote? Sure, the other one _seems_ more accurate, until you realise compilers aren't required by the Standard to do what most people expect (bytewise reinterpretation) in this case, so this answer is kinda better by warning about UB. Well, they downvoted them both, so let's assume there's an even better, encyclopaedic answer on the way... ha.

Comment: @underscore_d  I expect a comment by down voter and point out if something is wrong but ....  :)

Comment: Maybe they were super nitpicky. Just assigning an incompatible type to another is already undefined behavior, because of trap values. In this case: `pf=(float *)&a;`

Comment: @underscore_d Both answers are fine. They address different issues with the question.

Comment: I just wanted to explain why that specific value was being displayed and distinguish it from a garbage value.  The points made regarding undefined behavior are definitely relevant and will hopefully guide the OP in the right direction.